# mtext y-axis label that covers a two-tile plot

Tags: r, plot, label, axis

How do I use `mtext(side = 2,text="y-axis")` to place a y-axis label for both tiles in the example below? That is, instead of placing two separate y-axis labels, I want to be able to place a single label.

```
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=1),widths=1,heights=c(2,2),respect=FALSE)
par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi",type='l',ylab='')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to add an *outer margin* with `par(oma=...)`, suppress annotations with `ann=FALSE`, then add them manually in the outer margin with `mtext(..., outer=TRUE)` etc.

```
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=1),widths=1,heights=c(2,2),respect=FALSE)
par(mar = rep(0, 4), oma=c(4, 4, 4, 2), las=1)
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE, xaxt='n')
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE)

title("Hi", outer=TRUE)
mtext("x-axis", 1, 3, outer=TRUE)
mtext("y-axis", 2, 3, outer=TRUE, las=0)
```

Here's a reference: http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/

Also notice the `las` argument that turns all labels horizontal. It maks it easier to read and shows your audience you know your plotting :)

[image]