# Adding dotted line in between two plot windows

Tags: r, plot

I wish to produce a plot similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422787/2739669). However, I would like the solid line dividing these two windows to be dotted. I've searched around the internet a bit but I still havent found anything useful. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

```
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=1),widths=1,heights=c(2,2),respect=FALSE)
par(mar = rep(0, 4), oma=c(4, 4, 4, 2), las=1)
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE, xaxt='n')
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE)

title("Hi", outer=TRUE)
mtext("x-axis", 1, 3, outer=TRUE)
mtext("y-axis", 2, 3, outer=TRUE, las=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could over-write the upper box border of the lower plot with one of these:

```
  abline(h= par("usr")[4], lty=3,col="white",xpd=TRUE, lwd=2)

  # there is some bleed-through so to get a definite black-white dotted line needed to repeat the graphics call
  corners=par('usr')
  replicate(3, segments(x0= corners[1], x1= corners[2], 
                        y0= corners[4], y1= corners[4], 
                        lty=3,col="white",xpd=TRUE, lwd=2) )
```

Nuts. The png() output is different than the output on the interactive device (`quartz()`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think there's a bracket missing at the end of "replicate" code.

Answer (score 1):

Little workaround. Need to figure out where exactly you overplot the border. Would just go with something like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
par(lty=1)
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=1),widths=1,heights=c(2,2),respect=FALSE)
par(mar = rep(0, 4), oma=c(4, 4, 4, 2), las=1)
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE, xaxt='n')
plot(rnorm(100), type='l', ann=FALSE)
par(lty=2)
abline(h=3.27, col="white")
par(lty=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: trivial edit, put def.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) at the top of the code and, par(def.par) at bottom.